# Error Handling in Spring MVC

Tags: spring

Error Handling can be done via any of the following approach

Example1: Controller throws exception whichever service layer throws it

https://github.com/aasthasmile/Spring-Boot-MVC-WebBasedApplication/blob/master/src/main/java/csulb/edu/aasthajain/controller/UserController.java

Example2: Catching exception in controller and throwing Status Object at last with error message

https://github.com/SurendraVidiyala/SpringRestCrud/blob/master/src/main/java/com/javacrud/controller/RestController.java

Example3: Creating exception in Controller and throwing the exception directly

https://github.com/khoubyari/spring-boot-rest-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/khoubyari/example/api/rest/HotelController.java

Example4: Open Source project shopizer approach. catch exception in controller layer and sets the response status

https://github.com/shopizer-ecommerce/shopizer/blob/2.0.5/sm-shop/src/main/java/com/salesmanager/shop/controller/ReferenceController.java

Question:

1. Which one is the correct approach as standard and efficient practice?
2. Is there is any other good approach then the above, if yes, please let know in detail.

Thanks.

Comment: Any feedback or comments?

Comment: I prefer throw exception from service layer and always catch in controller and decide what the status and the error message to be for ui.